# Windows 10 Multiple Desktops - Equivalent Keyboard Shortcut of CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+LEFT/RIGHT in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

Recently had to switch from Ubuntu to Windows 10 for work.

I see Windows finally added multiple desktops.

CTRL + SUPER + LEFT/RIGHT  switch desktops which is great.

In Ubuntu CTRL + ALT + LEFT/ RIGHT do the same.

In Ubuntu you can also take the current application in focus to a new Desktop via

CTRL + ALT + SHIFT + LEFT / RIGHT

Is there an equivalent to this in Windows 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At time of writing, there are only three categories of keyboard shortcut for handling Virtual Desktops in Windows 10:

`Ctrl + Windows Key + D` – This creates a new virtual desktop and immediately switch to it.

`Ctrl + Windows Key + F4` – This closes the virtual desktop you are currently on.

`Ctrl + Windows Key + Left / Right` – This switches you to a virtual desktop on the left or right.

These are the only available keyboard shortcuts at the moment - there is currently (unfortunately) no way to move a window across.